# I call function but it didn't print any word

Tags: c++

I am writing a c++ code.
In this code, I call the function GetOption() first, but it appear nothing.
Can anyone help me?
Other functions have other purpose, but I'm not sure whether it will affect it. Thus I paste it all!
Below is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<fstream>
#include<boost/regex.hpp>
#include"ContactRec.h"
using namespace std;
using namespace boost;
int GetOption();
int main(){GetOption();}
ContactRec GetContactInfo()
{
    ContactRec id;
    ofstream myoutfile("directory.txt",ios::app); 
    regex reg_email("^\\w+([\\.-]?\\w+)*@\\w+([\\.-]?\\w+)*(\\.\\w{2,3})+$");
    regex reg_tel("^\\(?(\\d{3})\\)?-?(\\d{3})-(\\d{4})$"); 

        cout<<"enter your name."<<endl;
        cin.ignore(1024,'\n');
        getline(cin,id.Name);

        cout<<"enter your email."<<endl;
        cin>>id.Email;
        while (regex_match(id.Email,reg_email)==0)
        {
            cout<<"data wrong!!!!!!"<<endl;
            cin>>id.Email;
        }
        cout<<"enter your telephone numbers. EX:012-111-1111"<<endl;
        cin>>id.Phone;
        while(regex_match(id.Phone,reg_tel)==0)
        {
            cout<<"data wrong!"<<endl;
            cin>>id.Phone;
        }
        cout<<"Please enter the type(0)Family,(1)Friend,(2)Other"<<endl;
        int p;
        cin>>p;
        id.Type=(ContactType)p;
        myoutfile<<setiosflags(ios::left)<<setw(30)<<id.Name;
        myoutfile<<setiosflags(ios::left)<<setw(30)<<id.Email;
        myoutfile<<setiosflags(ios::left)<<setw(30)<<id.Phone;
        myoutfile<<setiosflags(ios::left)<<setw(30)<<id.Type<<endl;
        myoutfile.close();
    return id;
}
void PrintContactInfo(int type)
{   
    ContactRec person;

        ifstream myinfile;
        myinfile.open("directory.txt",ios::in);
        cout<<setiosflags(ios::left)<<setw(30)<<"name";
        cout<<setiosflags(ios::left)<<setw(30)<<"email";
        cout<<setiosflags(ios::left)<<setw(30)<<"telephone";
        cout<<setiosflags(ios::left)<<setw(30)<<"type"<<endl;

    string temp;
    if (type==-1)
    {
        while (myinfile)
        {
            getline(myinfile,temp);
            cout<<temp<<endl;

        }
    }
    else if(type==0)
    {
        while (myinfile)
        {
            getline(myinfile,temp);
            if (temp[70]=='0')
                cout<<temp<<endl;

        }
    }
    else if(type==1)
    {
        while (myinfile)
        {
            getline(myinfile,temp);
            if (temp[70]=='1') 
                cout<<temp<<endl;

        }
    }   
    myinfile.close();
}
int GetOption()
{
    int number=0;
    while(number!=5)
    {
        cout<<"(1)Add a new record"<<endl;
        cout<<"(2)Display the all contacts."<<endl;
        cout<<"(3)Display the contacts of family. "<<endl;
        cout<<"(4)Display the contacts of friends."<<endl;
        cout<<"(5)Exit."<<endl;
        cin>>number;
        if (number==1)
        GetContactInfo();
        if (number==2)
        PrintContactInfo(-1);
        if (number==3)
        PrintContactInfo(0);
        if (number==4)
        PrintContactInfo(1);

    }
}
```

Below is ContactRec.h

```
#include <string>
#include"ContactType.h"
using namespace std;
struct ContactRec
    {
    string Name;
    string Phone;
    string Email;
    ContactType Type;
};
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out,const ContactRec id)
{
    out<<id.Name;
    out<<id.Email;
    out<<id.Phone;
    out<<id.Type;
 }
```

Below is ContactType.h

```
enum ContactType{Family,Friend,Other};
```

Comment: You should change your check in the `while` loop because a User could enter -1 or 6, which are both != 5.

Comment: When you used the debugger, which line is causing the problem?

Comment: Please do not paste all the code, only the relevant code. Removing irrelevant stuff could actually help you find the problem before posting.

Comment: You might also want to say how exactly you compiled and ran it, and the precise output you're getting.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews The debugger didn't show any problem and any result.That is really confused me

Comment: You *must* return an `int` from `GetOption`, or change its return type to ´void`, otherwise the behaviour is undefined and anything can happen (including nothing).

Comment: @molbdnilo But I change it to `void` now, it still show nothing

Comment: Inside each function that `GetOption` calls, print the name of the function.  This will tell you which function gets called and a trace report.  I don't think the issue is in `GetOption`.

Comment: Please edit your post to include the structure `ContactRec`.

Comment: Usually when someone posts just an extract they get criticised for not giving enough info. Cut Jack some slack, he explained why he gave more code than strictly necessary. And why the vote to close? Cmon folks, be nice.

Comment: Why are you checking for '0' or '1' 70th symbol? You should check at least 90th. Whatever, it is a **bad** idea. You should overload operators >> and << for your class and use them.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I have paste it!

Comment: @JackHou: "The debugger didn't show any problem and any result."  He didn't mean to simply run it in debug mode.  He meant to step through it with the debugger and examine your variables and flow of execution.  [Click here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/79508/Mastering-Debugging-in-Visual-Studio-2010-A-Beginn) for some reading material on it (for Visual Studio).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see what's wrong with the code, at first sight we'd expect to see your "menu" being printed. So perhaps the trick here is to suggest some diagnostic ideas.

First, debugger. You say debugger shows no errors? But which lines does it actually go to? Can you step through your code? DO you see it go into getOption()? Do you see it go into your loop? See it execute the first cout << statement? My guess is not, not that I can see why.

Second add some print statements. Change your main to:

```
 int main(){
     cout << "hello" << endl;
     // GetOption();  <== removed
     cout << "goodbye" << endl;
 }
```

The idea here is to start with something that surely must work. If that doesn't work it's your environment that's the issue. Are you redirecting your output somewhere? If that does work, uncomment the GetOption() call, now what happens? Hopefully you get some clues by doing this kind of thing.

Indeed sometimes the trick to take out everything, start from something that works (eg. hello world) and add in your code piece by piece until you find what breaks. Here perhaps something your are including is breaking things (as per Thomas' suggestion).

Comment: I didn't see any issues either, but since we don't know what `ContactRec` is, there could be underlying issues, such as `std::string` vs. `char *`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
void GetOption()
{
    int number;

    do
    {
        cout<<"(1)Add a new record"<<endl;
        cout<<"(2)Display the all contacts."<<endl;
        cout<<"(3)Display the contacts of family. "<<endl;
        cout<<"(4)Display the contacts of friends."<<endl;
        cout<<"(5)Exit."<<endl;
        cin>>number;
        if (number==1)
        GetContactInfo();
        if (number==2)
        PrintContactInfo(-1);
        if (number==3)
        PrintContactInfo(0);
        if (number==4)
        PrintContactInfo(1);

    }while(number!=5);
}
```

Comment: This would work just as well as the original code. -1 unless you can explain why this is better.

Comment: I don't know why, but it didn't work in this method

Answer (score 0):

This code will actually [work](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=eee0b03415acfe336fcd3dc6d15a9829-50d9cfc8a1d350e7409e81e87c2653ba) (after obvious fixes and removal of references to code you haven't provided) and and print what it is supposed to print.
The problem is thru in that cin is not being checked for invalid input, thus if you input something like 'abc' instead of number routine will loop over forever printing same prompt.

Comment: The stated problem is that nothing gets printed, you say that the code (as we expect) does actually print the initial menu?

Comment: @djna yes it is check the link I've provided

Comment: So the original problem statement is wrong or some header he is using is causing the symptom. Either way we don't have a good problem to work on ...

Comment: Right, it is definitely something we haven't access to.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `int` as data type of your function `GetOption()` you must return something or you can change your data type to void. Hope it helps!